# Llamar variable de método a otro método

Tags: java

Hola quiero poner la variable nombre en el segundo método de sueldo , la variable nombre esta en otro método el cual es Saludar. Abajo comenté en la línea de código donde quiero que vaya el nombre ¿me podrían ayudar?

```java
package Gastos;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Gastos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        saludar(); 
    }
    
    public static void saludar() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Bienvenido/a, porfavor ingresa tu nombre:");
        String nombre = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Bienvenido/a:"+ nombre);
    }
    
    public static void sueldoygastos() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Indicame tu sueldo" + // Aquí debería ir el nombre obtenido en el método saludar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Entonces en ese caso, o la pones a nivel de clase, o la pasas de un metodo a otro. Te recomendaria leer sobre scope de variables (ambito de variables)

Comment: Como detalle, al final de los métodos donde crees un objeto Scanner, llamaría a sc.close() para cerrar el escáner.

Answer (score 2):

Si no quieres crear una clase a parte para guardar el nombre, vas a tener que devolver la variable en la función `saludar`, y luego enviarla como parámetro a la función `sueldoygastos`.

Quedaría algo así.

```java
package Gastos;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nombre = saludar();
        sueldoygastos(nombre);
    }

    public static String saludar() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Bienvenido/a, porfavor ingresa tu nombre: ");
        String nombre = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Bienvenido/a: " + nombre);

        return nombre;
    }

    public static void sueldoygastos(String nombre) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Indicame tu sueldo " + nombre); // Aquí debería ir el nombre obtenido en el método saludar);
    }
}
```

Como verás, al llamar a la función `saludar` asignas el resultado a la variable `nombre`: `String nombre = saludar();`. Luego llamas a la otra función pasándole la variable: `sueldoygastos(nombre);`

Para devolver un valor tienes que cambiar la definición de la función para indicar que devuelve una cadena `public static String saludar()`, y devolver el valor con `return nombre`.

Luego también cambias la definición de la función `sueldoygastos` para que reciba un parámetro, y ya puedes usarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes declarar una variable (`valorSaludar` ) y modificar el método `saludar()` para que retorne un valor tipo String ( `public static String saludar()`  )el cual se asignaría a la variable.

De esta forma podrías usar el valor obtenido por el método `saludar()`:

```
public class Gastos {

private static String valorSaludar = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       valorSaludar = saludar(); 
       
       //llama método donde imprime valor de el usuario.
       sueldoygastos();
    }
    
    public static String saludar() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Bienvenido/a, porfavor ingresa tu nombre:");
        String nombre = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Bienvenido/a:"+ nombre);

        return nombre;
    }
    
    public static void sueldoygastos() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Indicame tu sueldo " + valorSaludar);
    }
}
```

Como comenta @gbianchi es importante revises lo relacionado a :

[**Variables y su alcance, variables locales y variables de instancia**](http://cpcppw.es/java-tipodatos.html)

Comment: me parece extraño, que respondas una pregunta y no le des +1, [en un momento lo comente en el meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3757/premiar-a-los-nuevos-usuarios-que-elaboren-una-buena-pregunta)

Comment: Hola @JackNavaRow regularmente doy puntuacion a todas las preguntas que respondo, solo que estoy algo ocupado y esta ocasion se me fue haha!